# What is the correct use of Proxy in scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

my Code is

```html
import scrapy
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.exceptions import IgnoreRequest

class BlogSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogspider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.*****']

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': '5',
        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
     'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
     'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    }

    PROXY_LIST = '/path/to/proxy/list.txt'

    def parse(self, response):

     bannCheck = response.css('.lead ::text').extract_first();

        for title in response.css('.seo-directory-doctor-link'):
            yield {'title': title.css('a ::attr(href)').extract_first()}

        next_page = response.css('li.seo-directory-page > a[rel=next] ::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)
```

That is the way where i try to use `Proxy` and `CustomSettings` with a Download Delay from 5 but it's not working.

I don't know the location of `Settings.py` and how can i configure it?
Maybe some one can give me a example for this code?

Hope for your Support

Thanks

EDIT: Now i know i have to create settings.py in the folder where my project is saved.

I try the example https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies
But it don't work he don't use the proxy list.

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I worked with proxies very well as implementing it in this way.
I used this [scrapy-proxies](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies), and this is my organisation of code :

Put the `randomproxy.py` beside `settings.py`.

## Settings

Inside of your **`settings.py`** file put this :

```
# Retry many times since proxies often fail
RETRY_TIMES = 5
# Retry on most error codes since proxies fail for different reasons
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    # Fix path to this module
    'botcrawler.randomproxy.RandomProxy': 600,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}

PROXY_LIST = '/home/user/botcrawler/botcrawler/proxy/list.txt'
```

## Spider

And then in your spider code (in parse function), check if the proxy works fine by checking something on the page :

```
if not response.xpath('//title'):
        yield Request(url=response.url, dont_filter=True)
```

Hope that helped. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your Support.

Comment: is it normaly when the proxy list file don't exist he try to connect without proxy? That problem i have or why the settings.py don't work? I use your code for Settings.py but what i have to place in randomproxy.py?

Comment: My Start command is "scrapy runspider scraper.py -o out2.csv" and i put the randomproxy.py from the Github project on the folder.

Comment: Maybe i need to import in my Script? And how i can do that?

Comment: you don't need to import anything; What problem do you have exactly ? what type of errors ? Please explain more :)